# Date range filter in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

About the date range of Ruby

as the command I enter:

```
Date.today
=> Sat, 07 Jul 2018

Date.today.beginning_of_month
=>Sun, 01 Jul 2018

Date.today.end_of_month
=>Tue, 31 Jul 2018

Time.now.end_of_month
=>2018-07-31 23:59:59
```

I want to filter the data which created in the range from 2018/07/01 00:00 to 2018/07/31 23:59:59

Can I set the period like

```
@period_1 = Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month
=>Sun, 01 Jul 2018..Tue, 31 Jul 2018

@period_2 = Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month
=> 2018-07-01 00:00:00..2018-07-31 23:59:59
```

Will data created at 2018/07/31 22:31:43 include in the range of `@period_1`?

Or I could just use `@period_2`?

Comment: I just tested it a local db, and the first query seems to omit the timestamps in the last day

Comment: @user000001 It means the timestamps over 2018-07-31 00:00:00 will not show?

Comment: Correct, though this seems to contradict @VijayakumarS' answer.

Comment: You're right, use `to_time` method it show me beginning of the day

Comment: BTW, you can call `Time.current.all_month` to create the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [to_time](https://apidock.com/rails/String/to_time) method for any of them that only return a date

Answer (score 0):

You can use @period_1 or @period_2, Logically both means same range.

E.g: If you use from **2018/07/01 to 2018/07/31**, it also means the range from **2018/07/01 00:00:00 to 2018/07/31 23:59:59**

Comment: You can check with your local db records